# como puedo hacer un listado de item y actualizar solo un dato sin borrar los demas?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic, programación-móvil

Buenas noches comunidad tengo un problema, estoy desarrollando una app para registro de vehiculos en ionic con angular utilizando firebase, el CRUD funciona perfectamente, lo que pasa es que guarda un solo item no guarda mas sino que se actualiza el mismo item, lo que quiero es actualizar un dato por medio de un radiobutton al tomar el valor para guardarlo en la variable que quiero actualizar pero sucede unos pequeños problemas. Me he rendido completamente de como hacer esto necesito su ayuda comunidad. le dejare algunas fotos para que vean el codigo  y lo que quiero realizar, al final al actualizar el editCustm aparecen la variable estado vacia y quieron que ahi se guarde el dato del radiobutton. ayuda porfavor!! [image: aqui es la parte del servicio] [image: la parte del servicio]
[image: Este el el CRUD][image: Esto sucede cuando en el radiobutton envia el valor a la variable status]

Comment: Hola, puedes hacer un ejemplo funcional en [stackblitz](https://stackblit.com) para ayudarte? Asi sera mas facil entenderte y resolver tus dudas.

Comment: lo haria pero son muchas cosas que tiene el proyecto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola al ser un objeto el que deseas editar lo más lógico es obtener todos los datos del objeto, luego modificar el que se desea y enviar el objeto entero de nuevo mediante el update a firebase:

```
JorgeRef.update({
  id: {
   name: item.name
   modelo: item.modelo
   marca: item.marca
   placa: item.placa
   status: item.status
   color: item.color
   }
})
```

Comment: gracias lo probare